# Add Time To Javascript Game Timer If Condition Met

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement, jquery-events

**EDIT:**

I thought I'd try and add some clarity. Basically what I want is similar to Pole Position: cross the finish line and earn more time. Except in this case you match two numbers.

---

I have wanted to get better at Javascript and jQuery so I thought creating a game would be a great way to go about it.

The gist of the game is that you are given a number and the goal is to match that number.  I have everything working, including that when the goal is matched it adds to score. What I want now is to also add 30 seconds back to the time when the goal is matched.

I got it to add 30 seconds to the innerHTML but not the countdown. So if you were at 15 it would flash 45 then go back to 14.

I found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23025867/game-timer-javascript) and thought that I could change the

```
if (seconds == 0) {
        isRunning = true;
        seconds += 2;
```

to my condition and change it to seconds += 30; however nothing happens.

Here is my code. I am open to Jquery solutions as well if that is what you prefer to share.

```
var isWaiting = false;
var isRunning = false;
var seconds = 120;
var countdownTimer;
var finalCountdown = false;
var goalDiv = document.getElementById("goal").innerHTML;
var totalDiv = document.getElementById("total").innerHTML;

function GameTimer() {
    var minutes = Math.round((seconds - 30) / 60);
    var remainingSeconds = seconds % 120;

    document.getElementById('timerID').innerHTML = remainingSeconds;
    if (goalDiv == totalDiv) {
        isRunning = true;
        seconds += 30;

        if (seconds == 0) {
        $.mobile.changePage("index.html#youlost",{transition: "slideup"});
            clearInterval(countdownTimer); 
        } else {
            finalCountdown = true; 
        }

    } else {
        isWaiting = true;
        seconds--;
    }
}
countdownTimer = setInterval(GameTimer, 1000);
```

Comment: maybe you should try parseInt() ?

Comment: Could you post a http://jsfiddle.net?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you never update the value of `totalDiv` after you've initially set it.

```
var goalDiv = document.getElementById("goal").innerHTML;
var totalDiv = document.getElementById("total").innerHTML;
```

And then, your `GameTimer()` function just keeps checking the old value of the `totalDiv` over and over. So it will never increment the seconds counter.

You might want to change your code to recheck the value of `totalDiv` on each tick of the timer:

```
function GameTimer() {
    var minutes = Math.round((seconds - 30) / 60);   // also this does not make 
    var remainingSeconds = seconds % 120;            //    much sense..

    var totalDiv = document.getElementById("total").innerHTML;

    document.getElementById('timerID').innerHTML = remainingSeconds;
    var totalDiv = document.getElementById("total").innerHTML;

    //...
```

Here's [a JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mikkanu/ojwzorsm/) that shows a working version (based on your sample code, with a modifications, based on what my understanding of what you're tring to do)

And another thing. This not right either..

```
 seconds += 30;
 if (seconds == 0) {         // this won't be 0 unless seconds was -30 before..
    $.mobile.changePage("index.html#youlost",{transition: "slideup"});
        clearInterval(countdownTimer); 
 }
```

Comment: This fixed the zero issue that I didn't yet realize I created. Thank you. I'm still having issue with the timer though.  You are definitely putting me in the right direction though and have me thinking more.  I did notice that your fiddle had the issue that I had earlier. It would add 30 and then keep adding. I want it to add 30 and then count down again. So 60 becomes 90 then 89,88,87...

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.
First of all I wrote my own time .

```
var count = 120;
    function timer() {
            count--;
    $("#timerID").html(+count);
    }
```

Then....
1. I wrapped everything in a $(document).ready function.

2. I put my setInterval in a global variable.
3. My clearInterval pulls the variable and is inside my function and that checks the score for my condition.
4. Then I add 30 seconds and recall the timer.

Maybe not the best strategy but it works.